# Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state. while building clustered index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I get the following error while trying to create a clustered index

> The statement has been terminated.
> Msg 596, Level 21, State 1, Line 0
> Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
>
> Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
> A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

The index is:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
COMMIT

BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_CO_DES_INPUT 
ON dbo.CO_DES_INPUT(DESIGN_ID, PRODUCT_INPUT_NUM, INPUT_NAME)
          WITH(STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
               ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.CO_DES_INPUT 
  SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3) (KB3072779) - 11.0.6020.0 (X64)
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 (Build 9600: )

I have run

```
DBCC CheckDB ('concept-test') WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS
```

and it found no problems

I am afraid that my database is corrupt since I am getting this error. How do I correct my issue and get this index put on the table?

Comment: I do get the same error when I go to add a non clustered index on the same table.  I tried adding the non clustered first.  I got this error.  So I thought that I might have index corruption and tried to drop all indexes and recreate them.  That is when I got the error message I originally posted.  I might add that the Idera SQL Integrity check did find corruption on the indexes for this table.  Now the question is, how do I fix it.

Comment: Would it be possible that your operation fail when it finds out that there´s a constraint violation or something like that? Please take a look to this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518205/c-sharp-cmd-executescalar-cannot-continue-the-execution-because-the-session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518205/c-sharp-cmd-executescalar-cannot-continue-the-execution-because-the-session)

Answer (score 4):

Just a pointer re: SQL Server 2017 (where I was hitting this error) and some versions of 2016 to potentially save others some time:

Before SQL Server 2017 CU8 (also 2016 SP1 CU9 and 2016 SP2 CU1), there was an issue where partitioned tables with incremental stats would generate this error if the DML operation caused an automatic stats update.

Minimal KB page is here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4163478/fix-access-violation-when-incremental-statistics-automatically-updated

Installing a later CU than those listed above fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This can be caused by Corruption of Index,

The Best way to manage this is Drop the Old Index which is corrupt.

```
DROP INDEX dbo.CO_DES_INPUT.IX_CO_DES_INPUT
```

And than Run the query in questions, it should work fine if all records are unique. in the given columns.

Answer (score 3):

In a database configured for Always On Availability Groups, you may also encounter this behavior if the Availability Group is in SYNCHRONOUS mode and secondaries have gone offline or are suspended.  This is a side-effect experienced by application servers.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Something I've unwittingly found: When you are disabling / rebuilding indexes on an indexed view, you will get this same error if you try to rebuild one ore more of the non-clustered indexes prior to building the clustered or use REBUILD ALL.

Answer (score 2):

I always get this error when I have a running query, using an Always On AG Listener, using one of the AG databases and there is a failover:

**.Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 596, Level 21, State 1, Line 0
Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
.Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.**

Very easy to reproduce! Of course, there might be other reasons but this is the one particular instance I am getting this type of error...

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this issue in a fairly small C# program that uses Asynchronous Connections, but I am not sure 100% why.  Here is my repro program in case others want to give it a try - I suspect there is a series of things that have to line up perfectly for this to happen:

- Connection pooling enabled
- Using impersonation in the connection pool, disallowing reverting that impersonation context in the connection pool

```
void Main()
{
    var impersonateMyself = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

    var testCommand = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM sys.objects";
    var calls = Enumerable.Repeat(
        $@"{testCommand};",
        10
    );
    var impersonatedCalls = Enumerable.Repeat(
        $@"EXECUTE AS LOGIN = '{impersonateMyself} WITH NO REVERT';  {testCommand}; REVERT;",
        10
    );
    Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
    };

    // Scenario 1: Impersonated Calls, With connection pooling -- will randomly fail
    Parallel.ForEach(
        impersonatedCalls,
        c => new SqlAsync("Data Source=devsql2;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=true;Max Pool Size=2;").AsyncSqlCall<List<A>>(c, CommandType.Text, handleResultAsync, dict).Dump());

    Parallel.ForEach(
        impersonatedCalls,
        c => new SqlSync("Data Source=devsql2;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=true;Max Pool Size=2;").SyncSqlCall<List<A>>(c, CommandType.Text, handleResultSync, dict).Dump());


    // Scenario 2: Normal calls, with connection pooling -- should succeed every time
    Parallel.ForEach(
        calls,
        c => new SqlAsync("Data Source=devsql2;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=true;Max Pool Size=2;").AsyncSqlCall<List<A>>(c, CommandType.Text, handleResultAsync, dict).Dump());

    Parallel.ForEach(
        calls,
        c => new SqlSync("Data Source=devsql2;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=true;Max Pool Size=2;").SyncSqlCall<List<A>>(c, CommandType.Text, handleResultSync, dict).Dump());



// Scenario 3: Impersonated Calls, WITHOUT connection pooling -- should succeed every time
    Parallel.ForEach(
        impersonatedCalls,
        c => new SqlAsync("Data Source=devsql2;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=true;Max Pool Size=200;").AsyncSqlCall<List<A>>(c, CommandType.Text, handleResultAsync, dict).Dump());

    Parallel.ForEach(
        impersonatedCalls,
        c => new SqlSync("Data Source=devsql2;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=true;Max Pool Size=200;").SyncSqlCall<List<A>>(c, CommandType.Text, handleResultSync, dict).Dump());
}

public class SqlSync
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    public int Timeout {get; set;}

    public SqlSync(string connString)
    {
        _connectionString = connString;
        Timeout = 30;
    }

    public T SyncSqlCall<T>(string commandText, CommandType type, Func<SqlDataReader, T> handleResult, Dictionary<string, object> parameters = null)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandTimeout = Timeout;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            if (parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in parameters)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kvp.Key, kvp.Value ?? DBNull.Value);
            }

            conn.Open();

            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                return handleResult(rdr);
        }
    }
}

public class SqlAsync
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    public int Timeout { get; set; }

    public SqlAsync(string connString)
    {
        _connectionString = connString;
        Timeout = 30;
    }

    public Task<T> AsyncSqlCall<T>(string sp, CommandType commandType, Func<SqlDataReader, Task<T>> handleResult, Dictionary<string, object> parameters = null)
    {
        return AsyncSqlCall<T>(sp, commandType, (reader, token) => handleResult(reader), CancellationToken.None, parameters);
    }

    public async Task<T> AsyncSqlCall<T>(string commandText, CommandType type, Func<SqlDataReader, CancellationToken, Task<T>> handleResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Dictionary<string, object> parameters = null)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandTimeout = Timeout;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            if (parameters != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in parameters)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kvp.Key, kvp.Value ?? DBNull.Value);
            }

            await conn.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);

//          if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
//              await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
            using (var rdr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection, cancellationToken))
                return await handleResult(rdr, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}

public class A
{
    public string object_name { get; set; }
}

public static Func<SqlDataReader, Task<List<A>>> handleResultAsync = (SqlDataReader sdr) =>
{
    var result = new List<A>();
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        result.Add(new A { object_name = sdr.GetFieldValue<string>(0) });
    }
    return Task.FromResult(result);
};

public static Func<SqlDataReader, List<A>> handleResultSync = (SqlDataReader sdr) =>
{
    var result = new List<A>();
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        result.Add(new A { object_name = sdr.GetFieldValue<string>(0) });
    }
    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Relating to John Zabroski's post. I found this error is 100% reproduceable when I use EXECUTE AS USER  in conjunction with connection pooling.
The error occurs after pooling tries to reset the connection - the subsequent attemt to re-use the connection results in "Cannot continue execution because the session is in the kill state".

Looking in the SQL server log shows the underlying error
Error: 18059, Severity: 20, State: 1.
The connection has been dropped because the principal that opened it subsequently assumed a new security context, and then tried to reset the connection under its impersonated security context. This scenario is not supported. See "Impersonation Overview" in Books Online.